# Importing Three.js with npm

Tags: javascript, json, npm, three.js

Just tried to write up a basic three scene, and didn't seemed to be working with the npm installation of THREE.js. A bit newer with working with npm so not sure what quiet is wrong with my implantation. Can clarify anything if needed.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );    
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x87CEEb);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.pendChild( renderer.domElement );


const animate = function () {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

Comment: `document.body.pendChild` should be `document.body.appendChild`

Comment: You're using a bundler like Webpack/Snowpack/etc. right?